# How can I get pagination work on Meteor 1.5.2 with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, pagination

I’m trying to implement the pagination on newest Meteor 1.5.2
I get the message infinity below (message repeat again and again til cpu high):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of null
    at GridPaging.setDisplayedPages (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:120887)
    at GridPaging.componentWillReceiveProps (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:120871)
    at modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:18243
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:17708)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:18242)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:18179)
    at Object.receiveComponent (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:10730)
    at Object.updateChildren (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:17442)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:16976)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (modules.js?hash=2655cfff73e00fd13ccdff98af126d1e173cbf87:17080)
```

Please help to find out the solution, my codes are below:

ui/pages/ReactiveRegisters.js user interface

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Registers } from '../../api/registers';
import BootstrapPaginator from 'react-bootstrap-pagination';
import Loading from '../../components/Loading';

class ReactiveRegisters extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


    }
    renderRegister(register) {
        return (
            <li key={register._id}>{register.firstname}</li>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return ( !this.props.loading ? (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.props.registers.map(this.renderRegister)}
            </ul>
            <BootstrapPaginator
                pagination={this.props.pagination}
                limit={10}
                containerClass="text-center"
            />
        </div>
        ) : <Loading />);
    }
}

ReactiveRegisters.propTypes = {
    registers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    pagination: PropTypes.object,
};

export default createContainer(() => {  
    pagination = new Meteor.Pagination(Registers, {
        filters: {},
        sort: {},
        perPage: 10,
        reactive: true,
        debug: true,
    });
    return {
        loading: !pagination.ready(),
        registers: pagination.getPage(),
  };
}, ReactiveRegisters);
```

server/publications.js to publish the collection.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Events } from '../events';
import { Registers } from '../registers';
import { publishPagination } from 'meteor/kurounin:pagination'

publishPagination(Registers);
```

api/registers.js to define the collection.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Registers = new Mongo.Collection('registers');

Meteor.method({........
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `server/publications.js` import `api/registers.js` first, before doing `publishPagination(...)`?

Comment: *Styx, Sorry I forget to post all those import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the error message - it is telling you:

```
Cannot read property 'ready' of null
```

Look for `ready` in your code and it will show you where it might have happened. There is only one place in the code you posted, so it means that the `pagination` variable is null, ie the call to `new Meteor.Pagination` didn't return anything.

So your pagination isn't working (as @styx suggests) - probably a problem in your publish and subscribe code. You should be able to work it out from there.

You can save yourself a lot of time posting here if you

1. Read the error messages and interpret them
2. Write defensive code that checks the returns of function calls.

These are basic programming techniques you should be following if you want to become an adept programmer

Comment: Since this error is happening on the client, going into the debugger and checking "Pause on Caught Exceptions" would also quickly help pinpoint the place in the code where the exception is occurring.

Comment: @Michel Floyd, thank you very much for your answer, I will try to find the problem follow your suggestion.